# Using Codeforces API to get information about all ACs of a user on CF questions through discord bot (discord.py) - json file handling error in python

Tags: python, json, api, discord, discord.py

I was trying to make a discord bot that would give me information about the questions in which the user that i enter has gotten ACs. For this I fetched the json file from CF API and converted it to dictionary to access it's key which held this information, I have attached the format of the fetched json. The problem is it gives me an error on the line where I am accessing the key and another error that I can't make head or tail of, I am attaching the error too. Can anyone please tell me where I messed up because I'm really new to this framework as well as python, I am attaching my code below too.

**Code**

```
import discord
import requests
import json
token = '(my_token)'
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!stalk"):
        handle = ""
        words = message.content
        for word in words[1:]:
            handle += word
        await message.channel.send(handle + ': (last correctly solved problem name) ')
        link = "https://codeforces.com/api/user.status?handle="
        link += handle
        request_info = requests.get(link)
        json_obj = dict(request_info.json())
        last_correct_problems = []
        for submissions in json_obj['result']:
            if submissions['verdict'] == 'OK':
                last_correct_problems.append(submissions['problem']['name'])
        for problem in last_correct_problems:
            await message.channel.send(problem + ', ')
client.run(token)
```

**Error**

> Ignoring exception in on_message

> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\envs\balalalabot\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
>
> > await coro(*args, **kwargs)

> File "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/labsheets/new_stuff/discbalalabot/bot.py", line 23, in on_message
> for submissions in json_obj['result']:
>
> > KeyError: 'result'

**Output on discord**

- nandini Today at 14:23
- !stalk prabhu4
- balalala BOT Today at 14:23
- stalk prabhu4: (last correctly solved problem name)

**API Link**
[you can refer to the user.status method on this page](https://codeforces.com/apiHelp)

**JSON Fetched**

```
{"status":"OK",
"result":[{"id":88388369,
"contestId":702,
"creationTimeSeconds":1596059866,
"relativeTimeSeconds":2147483647,
"problem":{"contestId":702,
"index":"A",
"name":"Maximum Increase",
"type":"PROGRAMMING",
"rating":800,
"tags":["dp","greedy","implementation"]},
"author":{"contestId":702,
"members":[{"handle":"Prabhu4"}],
"participantType":"PRACTICE",
"ghost":false,"startTimeSeconds":1469804400},
"programmingLanguage":"GNU C++17",
"verdict":"OK",
"testset":"TESTS",
"passedTestCount":32,
"timeConsumedMillis":46,
"memoryConsumedBytes":3788800},
{"id":88388346,
"contestId":702,
"creationTimeSeconds":1596059822,
"relativeTimeSeconds":2147483647,
"problem":{"contestId":702,
"index":"A",
"name":"Maximum Increase",
"type":"PROGRAMMING",
"rating":800,
"tags":["dp","greedy","implementation"]},
"author":{"contestId":702,
"members":[{"handle":"Prabhu4"}],
"participantType":"PRACTICE",
"ghost":false,
"startTimeSeconds":1469804400},
"programmingLanguage":"GNU C++17",
"verdict":"WRONG_ANSWER",
"testset":"TESTS",
"passedTestCount":0,
"timeConsumedMillis":15,
"memoryConsumedBytes":3788800}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start this off by advising you to use the aiohttp library instead of the requests library, as requests is blocking while aiohttp is async.
It starts with the first couple of lines in your code. You want to get all the words except the command. message.content isn't a list of words, but it's a string of the message. You'll have to split it into words by using message.content.split(' ').
Now you should get the right results when you get the json file.
Next requestinfo.json() returns a dict and making a dict isn't neccesary.
When you've implemented this it should work.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much I was stuck because of a plain .split for so long, Thank you so much for the help.